# Load a different form on different pages using the same page template

Tags: forms, kentico, kentico-12

Kentico 12, not MVC:
I have a page template that is used on several pages.  On some of those pages I want to display a form. (a biz form from the Forms application) I don't necessarily want the same form on each of those pages. I need a way to specify which form to display.  I expect I could create a field in the page type to specify the form name, but it would be nicer to be able to have designers add a page with the form on it, and have a repeater display that page in a webpartzone on the aforementioned page template.  I'm not sure how to do this, though.  Anyone have an example or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re using portal engine, then you should easily be able to add an editor zone to your template. Content editors can then add the online form widget to individual pages. The widgets work at page level rather than template level, so should give the control you

The page from the docs will show how to setup an editor zone:
https://docs.kentico.com/k12/developing-websites/preparing-widgets-for-users/setting-up-widget-zones-on-pages

Answer (score 1):

In addition to adding a widget zone, you can simply add an editable text webpart to the template and in the WYSIWYG editor you can click on the BizForm icon to insert that widget there. This doesn't require you to change the page template to a widget zone template.